# Is there any python implementation for text replacement with truetype fonts?

Tags: django, image, fonts, truetype

I have searched and there are some php or flash based solutions, but none in Python.

PIL (Python Image Library) could be the starting point, but if anybody knows something done or half done I will gladly use it for my Django projects, finish or polish the library and release it for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually fairly easy in Django. Jacob Kaplan-Moss [posted about it](http://jacobian.org/writing/improved-text-image-view/) years ago. I used this on my site for a while.

Apparently there's a [django-rendertext project](http://code.google.com/p/django-rendertext/) based on that code, but I haven't used it.

Comment: Wow, django-rendertext looks good, I bit verbose maybe because other solutions parse css to get the style information. I'll give it a try definetly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The nicest text comes from PyCairo, but having said that, I've not seen any project that just spits out images with the desired text in that manner, for any web framework.